# How to apply css class on clicked element of iframe with specific attribute value?

Tags: jquery

After getting the content of iframe being clicked, it is filtered to get the very first element with custom attribute `data-type = filled`. But I am not able to apply a class on that particular element.

Here is my code:

```
var clicked_content = event.target.outerHTML, // gives the content being clicked

content = $(clicked_content).find("*[data-type='filled']:first").andSelf().html(); // this gives me the required content

// this was supposed to add a class to particular element
content.parent.addClass("highlight");
```

I also did tried to do it this way:

```
$(event.target).children().find("*[data-type='filled']:first").andSelf().addClass('highlight');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`outerHTML` and `html()` return strings. A string has no parent.

Maybe you want

```
$(event.target).find("*[data-type='filled']:first").andSelf()
    .parent().addClass("highlight");
```

Note that [andSelf](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) has been deprecated and replaced with `addBack`.

If you try to apply a class on *"the very first element with custom attribute data-type = filled"*, then you should do

```
$(event.target).find('[data-type=filled]').eq(0).addClass("highlight");
```

EDIT : as you want  to also match the clicked element if it has the proper data-type, then I suggest

```
$(event.target).find('*').addBack().filter('[data-type=filled]').eq(0)
   .addClass("highlight");
```

Comment: then what's the alternative for andSelf ?

Comment: I gave a link giving an alternative but I don't understand why you use it to start with.

Comment: the 2nd code snippet seems to work but it has a little limitation .i.e. it works when there are multiple elements clicked but when a single element is clicked it does not work

Comment: @atif I don't understand your comment. Maybe you should build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to make it clear ?

Comment: if clicked content contains multiple elements like div with div and so on etc, then this solution works, but if the clicked element is single and by itself the desired one to be highlighted, then it does not work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24438/discussion-between-atif-and-dystroy)